# standard topology on $\mathbb {R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, definition

When we talk about the "standard" topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, does it mean the topology having basis as balls with the Euclidean distance, i.e:$d(x,y) = \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+ \cdot \cdot \cdot + (x_n^2-y_n^2)}$?

Comment: Yepp, or the product which is equivalent

Comment: Yes. Including the case $n=1.$ Also called "the usual topology on $R^n$."